# VSCode ESLint async functions not supported

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, eslint

I am trying to configure ESLint on VSCode, but I get this error when I use async/await functions:

```
Async functions are not supported until Node.js 7.6.0. The configured version range is '>=6.0.0'. (node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax)"
```

But here is my .eslintrc.json:

```
{
  "root": true,
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:node/recommended"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018
  },
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "mocha": true
  }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try setting `"es6": true` under `"env"`

Comment: What version of Node do you have installed?

Comment: @KenoClayton tried it, and still doesn't work

Comment: @davidrv87 v8.9.4

Comment: [Try this link](https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-node/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unsupported-features.md), it might help you solve the issue

Answer (score 4):

Adding

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=7.6.0"
  }
```

to the module's package.json file should resolve these errors.

From https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-node#readme ,

> Note: It recommends a use of the "engines" field of package.json. The "engines" field is used by node/no-unsupported-features/* rules.

Comment: After this change, VSCode reload may be required